# Is there a name for overriding parent methods by inheriting from a different class?

Tags: python

I have a class with some methods that I want to test, but they are calling other methods that rely on integrations, so I want to override those in my test. I can do this by inheriting from a different class that overrides the base class method.

What I'm wondering is if this "pattern" has a name?

Example:

```py
# api.py
class API:
    ...
    def get_names(self) -> list[str]:
         names = self._fetch_names_from_database()  # Calls external resources
         # Do other stuff ...
         return names
```

```py
# test_api.py
from api import API

class MockDatabase:
    def _fetch_names_from_database(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ["test_name_1", "test_name_2"]

class TestAPI(MockDatabase, API):
    pass

test_api = TestAPI()
# run unit tests for test_api.get_names()
```

Comment: It's a bit like mix-ins, but being abused to do a sort of partial mocking. Compose instead, the mock database (or its real equivalent) should be a _collaborator_ of the API - `names = self._db.fetch_names()`.

Comment: This would be cleaner if `API` were a base class that *required* `_fetch_names_from_database` to be defined (either in a concrete subclass or inherited from some mix-in) by any children. (Take care that a mix-in providing a concrete definition for an abstract method must appear *before* the abstract class in the list of base classes.)

Comment: Looked at in this light, it's basically dependency inversion, but using inheritance instead of function arguments.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. In reality I'm not in control of the implementation of `API`; it's an ABC that I have to inherit from, which calls an "internal" method that I would like to intercept/change without having to override that method in every subclass, thus the use of a mixin class.